# Wha't is "linear replacement"

Tags: linear-algebra

What is "linear replacement"?

In Quadratic Form, some of my books say that non- degerating "linear replacement" will standardize a quadratic form.

Some of my books say that is a linear transformation.

Is "linear replacement" a linear transformation? The book say "linear replacement" because before there linear transformation hasn't be defined.

standardize a quadratic form is doing rotation(a linear transformation under one basis) or a change of basis?

Answer (score 0):

Linear replacement means linear change of basis, i.e. you "replace" you basis with another one, in which the quadratic form has diagonal form.